# Are Pokémon animals?

Tags: pokemon

Let's get technical here. Have you ever seen Pikachu excrete? What about Charizard? Or Greninja? No! Well, I don't think anyone has. Is that a sign of them not being actual animals? Let's recall the seven vital characteristics for life: [Mrs. Gren](https://basicbiology.net/biology-101/mrs-gren).

- Movement
- Respiratory
- Sensitivity
- Growth
- Reproduction
- Excretion
- Nutrition

We've seen Pikachu move (obviously), breathe, touch, and eat.

Does Pikachu grow? Does he excrete?

I am missing one thing out here: reproduction. But we all know Pokémon reproduce, if not by normal means.

Throughout the series, we haven't seen Pikachu grow at all, or other Pokémon. Does evolving count?

We've never seen a Pokémon excrete.

Therefore, can we say they are animals?

***Let me make it clear that this is only out of interest, and I have not gone basukas!***

Comment: Pokémon = Pocket ***Monsters***.

Comment: **Gengars** used to be human but are now ghosts; "*"It apparently wishes for a traveling companion. Since it was once human itself, it tries to create one by taking the lives of other humans."*". **Kadabras** are ex-human "*"A theory exists that this Pokémon was a young boy who couldn't control his psychic powers and ended up transformed into this Pokémon."*" as are **Yamasks** "*“Each of them carries a mask that used to be its face when it was human. Sometimes they look at it and cry."*

Comment: Guzzlords don't excrete (apparently) "*"A dangerous Ultra Beast, it appears to be eating constantly, but **for some reason its droppings have never been found."***"

Comment: In the games, each individual Pokemon has a height and weight that fluxes from one to the next. We may not see it in the shows/movies, but the game mechanics support it.

Comment: Don't Pokémon trainers always clean pokeballs? They actually clear poops...

Comment: When was the last time we saw any TV character excrete? Occasionally, on some shows, perhaps, but we shouldn't assume that humans on most of those shows aren't animals.

Comment: Also, the 'evolutions' of a lot of them mimic real life animal growth stages, particularly a lot of the bug-types, who go through the larva, pupa, and adult stages. (Or in the case of some, nymph and adult)

Comment: @Michael Just yesterday, I saw an Elephant poop on BBC Earth. I almost vomited.

Comment: If you think an ice cream cone, pile of rubbish, set of gears, plants or literal rocks are animals, then yes, Pokemon are animals.

Comment: Pokemon do excrete. There was one episode of the cartoon where Gary finds a pokemon fossil and starts bragging about it. A professor-type character examines it and confirms that it is indeed a fossil, a coprolite, i.e. ancient pokemon poop.

Comment: @ClintEastwood , Thanks so much! I thought I heard something like that somewhere with Gary, but I couldn't recall it! Is it in _The Indigo League?_

Comment: Dropping are not excretion, it's egestion.
Urinating/sweating/exhaling is the process or excretion.

Egestion is unusable matter remaining from ingested food.
Excretion is the removal of metabolic waste

Comment: by this reasoning, is Ash human? Do you see him 'excrete' or 'egest'  : p

Comment: Well, anime characters do sweat a lot.

Comment: Aren't some of them plants?

Comment: "*SO: Each Pokemon does have a value but I don't consider those data as parameters. I prefer to think of them as real, living creatures. It's the same way that if you have a pet and someone else has the same breed of dog, it's a different dog. That way people can play the game and my Pokemon will be different to your Pokemon even if they're the same type.*" - Creatures, says one of the guys who invented them; https://www.wired.co.uk/article/pokemon-interview

Comment: Can't really consider something like MUK to be an animal

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This question has been the topic for [great discussion](https://www.pokecommunity.com/archive/index.php/t-313046.html); in providing research for my answer, I even found a fair few discussion posts on Reddit, though I can not seem to find them, now.; however [there is evidence of regular animals existing in the Pokémon universe](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world), where the lack there of appears to be the most popular argument for Pokémon being animals.

At the end of the day, Pokémon are *monsters*; after all, Pokémon is a [portmanteau](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91306/what-do-you-call-the-process-of-combining-two-words-to-create-a-new-one) of "pocket" and "monster". Some of them are *based* off animals, and thus act like and can fill the roles of particular animals; others are based off plants, or even inanimate objects. Whether they are actually *considered* animals is an entirely different story, and there is not enough conclusive evidence.

---

This question appears to correlate [the MRS GREN acronymn](http://basicbiology.net/biology-101/mrs-gren/) with *being an animal*. In actual fact, [the MRS GREN acronymn](http://basicbiology.net/biology-101/mrs-gren/) does not specifically identify an animal; it identifies a living organism. We can say without doubt that they *are* living organisms. Let's take a closer look at [the MRS GREN definition of a living organism](http://basicbiology.net/biology-101/mrs-gren/).

#### Movement

Pokémon definitely move. They would not be the source of entertainment they are if they just sat there all day. Some move more than others, while some barely move at all, but there is always some degree of movement capabilities.

[image: A group of Pokémon run towards the camera.]

#### Respiratory

We do not really see much in the way of breathing, but every now and again, we see a Pokémon that is short of breath (often being out of breath after some overly physical action such as running or taking a severe beating). You do not get short of breath if you do not need to breathe in the first place.

[image: A Bulbasur breathes.]

#### Sensitivity

We often see examples of physical sensitivity in Pokémon, usually after taking a big hit or being defeated in battle. We also know that they have a physical endurance level (i.e. they "take damage"), because they *can* be defeated in battle, and often have to be healed.

[image: A Pikachu lies defeated after battle. Note the clear expression of pain.]

#### Growth

Pokémon grow in two ways. They grow in size, and when they reach certain conditions, they evolve and grow into new Pokémon. We often only clearly see the size difference when the Pokémon evolves; however, in some of the games (notably Pokémon Go), you can catch the same Pokémon in a variety of heights and weights.

[image: Eevee and its evolution Jolteon in Pokémon Go. Note the height and weight; note that they are marked as "XS", symbolising that these particular Pokémon are of a smaller weight and height in comparison with the average for that Pokémon.]

#### Reproduction

We know that Pokémon reproduce, because they lay and hatch from eggs. In fact, [Pokémon breeding](https://pokemondb.net/mechanics/breeding) is a commonly employed mechanic used to catch Pokémon of particular rarities and strengths.

[image: A Wynaut hatching from an egg.]

#### Excrement

OK, so we do not see Pokémon poop. There is a good reason for that; it is a video game and TV series primarily targeted at children. It is one of those things that just go without saying. We *do*, however, see *references* to Pokémon excrementing waste, primarily through Pokédex readings:

> Darumaka's **droppings** are hot, so people used to put them in their clothes to keep themselves warm. 
>   <sup>- [Daramuaka's Pokédex reading in Pokémon X and Pokémon OmegaRuby](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Darumaka_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Pok.C3.A9dex_entries_2)</sup>
>
> A dangerous Ultra Beast, it appears to be eating constantly, but **for some reason its droppings have never been found**. 
>   <sup>[- Guzzlord's Pokédex reading in Pokémon Moon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Guzzlord_(Pok%C3%A9mon))</sup>

The latter has been used to say that Guzzlord *does not* excrete; but on the contrary, this goes to show that Pokémon in general *do*. After all, if they *did not*, it would not be any mystery why one particular Pokémon's droppings have not been found.

#### Nutrition

We see Pokémon eat all the time. Ensuring your Pokémon has a nutritious diet is also often an employed mechanic in-game.

[image: Pikachu and Togepi, eating.]

---

In summary, in contrast with part of the question, Pokémon *can* be considered living organisms; however, there is only discussion and debate about whether or not they are actually considered *animals*.

After all, Pokémon are fictional organisms. The closest *real* organisms we have are predominantly *animals*. If they existed in the real world, they could quite possibly be classed as a completely *seperate* organism due to the clear distinction of both ability and comprehension. Since that is not the case, we can't really try to classify them with non-fictional constraints.

Comment: Per the criteria in the original post, Ash is not a living thing, either.  After all, the show's been on for decades, and he's lived through like, 4 sets of clothing (amazingly high for an anime character) but he hasn't grown an inch...or pooped.

Comment: He has definetley grown. After all, if he did not grow,  why did he have to *wait* until the age of 10 to be eligable for a Pokémon license? If he was *always* a ten year old boy, it would not have been such a big deal, in the pilot episode, when he wakes up on his birthday and rushes off to collect his first Pokémon; he would have just turned around, one day, and decided to set off.  I think we are confusing practical reality for TV tropes. In practical reality, none of them are living. They are fictitious TV and video game characters. Or maybe a wizard did it..

Comment: Obviously Ash is an android programmed to believe he is a ten-year-old boy.  They gave him false memories of his prior life, arranged the building in a way he would 'remember' and set him off.  This can't be disproven via canon material (it's a really good android) and makes just as much sense as "they never poop because we never see them poop".

Comment: Excrement is not the process of excretion, it's egestion.
Urinating/sweating/exhaling is the process or excretion.

Egestion is unusable matter remaining from ingested food.
Excretion is the removal of metabolic waste

Comment: @user001 If there was that much distinction between excretion and egestion, the acronym would be MRS GREEN, obviously.

Comment: @MrLister Ha, except that egestion is not necessary to classify life. Many small creatures do not egest as they metabolise everything they take in (especially if they have external lysosyme system).
So the answer should refer to the Pokemon breathing and sweating (excretion not excrement), which they do often, it does not even need to reference urinating.

Comment: @user001, except the question specifically *questions* excrementation.

Comment: @Gnemlock It asks about excretion. Where/What is excrementation

Comment: Ok we admit that evolution is part of the growth of a Pokémon, but what about Pokémon who does not evolve ? I take as an example : Dunsparce or any Legendary (almost any).

Comment: @Jeff - you're mistaken. Ash feasts on the life force of young girls, replacing them once every decade or so, once they're a used-up husk.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there IS conclusive evidence that Pokémon are animals. At least in the game continuity. There is an NPCs, IIRC from the 4th gen games, that literally says "Pokémon and other animals" which leads to two conclusions:

1) There are ordinary animals in their worlds (in the anime we already knew that though)
2) "and other animals" implies that those characters classify Pokémon as animals

So they are not just "other versions of our animals while being their own thing" but actually animals.

I will check how I can make a screenshot. I need to find the game first, then I will edit the comment. As long as I have not edited it, feel free to ignore it. But I definitely have seen it. I only need to find it again.

Comment: Some say Yakusoku is still trying to find his copy of pokemon to this very day...