# What exactly are and what's the relation of the Pokémon with the environment?

Tags: pokemon

I mean from an in-universe perspective. There are dossiers and encyclopedias around there, but what are Pokémon? They seem to be mostly animals but are they really animals, are they aliens or are they something else entirely? All I've seen is that the characters are fighting between species or being captured for people. Is this all they really do? How these Pokemons affect the planet environment? the fights are really necessary? The innate features of these suggest so, but why?

Comment: [History of the pokemon world](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_world).

Comment: the question suggested in [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157893/are-pok%c3%a9mon-animals) parcially solves the question in to state these are living organisms but the purpose is not explained.

Comment: "Purpose" implies they have an in-universe creator.  Maybe they just *are*.

Comment: Im editing the idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the fictional world* they inhabit, Pokémon would seem to exist *in the place of* animals, meaning that the humans of this world don't get milk from cows, but from [Miltanks](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Moomoo_Farm); they don't keep cats as pets, but [Meowths](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mom_(Alola)); and they don't pit roosters against each other for sport, because they have Pokémon for that.

(*It may be better to say "worlds," since the continuities of the anime, the main series of games, Pokémon Go, Pokémon Conquest, etc. seem to take place in different worlds with different rules. Luckily, the differences between these worlds aren't especially relevant to this discussion, so we can talk about a single "world," albeit imprecisely.)

Looking carefully at the games and anime, there's plenty of evidence for the existence of [real-world animals in the Pokémon world](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world). However, these references get less and less common as time goes on—as the creators of this world come up with new and exciting Pokémon to take the place of mundane creatures. As it stands, the writers and designers seem to reference real animals only when absolutely necessary: For everyday purposes, the fauna of our Earth do not exist.

Numerous Pokémon reportedly came into the Pokémon world [from other planets or other dimensions.](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Extraterrestrial_Pok%C3%A9mon) Others appear to have been created by humans, intentionally or not. (some Ghost-type Pokémon are said to come from a vaguely defined spirit world; at least one is supposed to be [the ghost of a human person!](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Yamask_(Pok%C3%A9mon)))By contrast with these unusual examples, we're led to believe that the vast majority of Pokémon are native to their universe in the same way that squirrels and antelopes are native to ours.

But many of these Pokémon are not like animals. [Legendary](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Legendary_Pok%C3%A9mon) and [Mythical](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mythical_Pok%C3%A9mon) Pokémon, in their world, have the status that mythical creatures, folk heroes, and gods have in ours. Kyogre, Groudon, Regigigas, and especially Arceus feature in various creation myths passed down by human cultures. The veracity of these ancient myths can perhaps be disputed, but the role that the [guardian deities](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Guardian_deities) play in protecting their islands is demonstrated explicitly in Pokemon Sun and Moon.

So, while in the wild, undisturbed by humans, **most Pokémon live like real-world animals,** while others wait at the tops of mountains or deep in caves for the time when their godlike powers are needed.

When humans get involved, it does seem at first blush like Pokémon do little other than get captured and then fight each other for the humans' amusement. These are the mechanics of the games, and in an out-of-universe sense, these mechanics are the reason Pokémon exist. In-universe, however, the creators have always made it clear that the best humans treat their Pokémon with the same respect afforded to fellow humans, and Pokémon help humans out in many ways other than participating in blood sport:

- As early as Pokémon Red and Blue, you can find [a old man with a Machop in Vermilion City](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vermilion_City#Construction_site): The man wants to construct a building, and the Machop is pounding the earth flat for him.
- Trainers groom Pokémon to compete in [Pokémon Contests,](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Contest) a kind of dog show/beauty pageant event.
- In the Alola region, you can [page a Pokémon](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ride) to transport you across water, fly you from island to island, carry you like a baby while pushing large stone cubes into holes, etc.
- Trainers can direct their Pokémon as [performers in movies](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9star_Studios).

Trained Pokémon are like pets, only better, because they have near-human intelligence and a bunch of cool powers. With all this potential to save labor and create beauty in the world, is it really necessary for people to have their pets fight each other?

No! But, if your pets can shoot lightning and psychic energy and vines at each other and then be restored to perfect health in a few seconds by a magic machine, then why wouldn't you?

Comment: Great answer, detailed and  I didnt think of this way.